# How can i design Schema for below product using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
name: aaaa shirts
category: shirts
subcategory: [{
        type: slimline,
        model: [{
                "type": "twill",
                "colour": [{
                        "name": "red",
                        "image": "red.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "white",
                        "image": "white.jpg"
                    }
                ],
                "size": [{
                        "val": "32",
                        "price": "1000"
                    },
                    {
                        "val": "24",
                        "price": "1244"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "denim",
                "colour": [{
                        "name": "red",
                        "image": "red.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "white",
                        "image": "white.jpg"
                    }
                ],
                "size": [{
                        "val": "32",
                        "price": "1000"
                    },
                    {
                        "val": "24",
                        "price": "1244"
                    }
                ]
            }

        ]
    },
    {
        type: superslim,
        model: [{
                "type": "denim",
                "colour": [{
                        "name": "red",
                        "image": "red.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "white",
                        "image": "white.jpg"
                    }
                ],
                "size": [{
                        "val": "32",
                        "price": "1000"
                    },
                    {
                        "val": "24",
                        "price": "1244"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "dobby",
                "colour": [{
                        "name": "red",
                        "image": "red.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "white",
                        "image": "white.jpg"
                    }
                ],
                "size": [{
                        "val": "32",
                        "price": "1000"
                    },
                    {
                        "val": "24",
                        "price": "1244"
                    }
                ]
            }

        ]
    }
]
```

Above is my product design example  i want to create Schema for this .how can i create Schema for above product .

how can i modify my schema design

```
'use strict';

import mongoose from 'mongoose';
var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name          :     String,
  category      :     String,
  subcategory   :     ??
  description   :    String,
  created_at    : { type: Date },
  updated_at    : { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  updated:        {type: Date, default: Date.now}
}, { versionKey: false });


export default mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

For example i select slimline i need to send model (twill , denim , dobby) with images and sizes(28,30,32,36) with color based on color(red , white) selection also i need to change the shirt image based on selected color
any one give some suggestion ? help me out move forward

Comment: For array u use [type]  like  [String]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Schema Defination and model.js
var ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    category:String,
    subcategory:[{
        type:String,
        model:[{
            type:String,
            colour:[{
                name:String,
                image:String
            }],
            size:[{
                val:Number,
                price:Number
            }]
        }]
    }],
    description:String,
    created_at:{ type: Date },
    updated_at:{ type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updated:{type: Date, default: Date.now}
}, { versionKey: false },{strict: false});
export default mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

Storing Product Details in Database Collection 
1. Static Storing

```
//Static Storing into Database
var ProductSchema = require('path/to/ProductSchema.js');
app.post('/Store_Product_Details',function (req,res) {
    var Name = 'Mens Formal Shirts';
        var Category = 'Shirts';
    var SubCategory = [{
        type: "slimline",
        model: [{
            "type": "twill",
            "colour": [{
                "name": "red",
                "image": "red.jpg"
            },
                {
                    "name": "white",
                    "image": "white.jpg"
                }
            ],
            "size": [{
                "val": 32,
                "price": "1000"
            },
                {
                    "val": 24,
                    "price": "1244"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "type": "denim",
            "colour": [{
                "name": "red",
                "image": "red.jpg"
            },
                {
                    "name": "white",
                    "image": "white.jpg"
                }
            ],
            "size": [{
                "val": 32,
                "price": 1000
            },
                {
                    "val": 24,
                    "price": 1244
                }
            ]
        }

        ]
    },{
        type: "superslim",
        model: [{
            "type": "denim",
            "colour": [{
                "name": "red",
                "image": "red.jpg"
            },{
                "name": "white",
                "image": "white.jpg"
            }
            ],
            "size": [{
                "val": 32,
                "price": 1000
            },{
                "val": 24,
                "price": 1244
            }
            ]
        },{
            "type": "dobby",
            "colour": [{
                "name": "red",
                "image": "red.jpg"
            },
                {
                    "name": "white",
                    "image": "white.jpg"
                }
            ],
            "size": [{
                "val": 32,
                "price": 1000
            },
                {
                    "val": 24,
                    "price": 1244
                }
            ]
        }

        ]
    }
    ]
    var Description = 'Mens Formal Wear';
    var date = new Date();
    var ProductData = new ProductSchema({
        name:Name,
        category:Category,
        subcategory:SubCategory,
        description:Description,
        created_at:date
    })
    ProductData.save(function (err,Status) {
        if(!err){
            res.send("Product Stored Successfully");
        }else {
            res.send("Oops! Something went Wrong");
        }
    })
});
```

2.) Dynamic Storing / From Controller

```
//Dynamically Storing or from Controller
var ProductSchema = require('path/to/ProductSchema.js');
app.post('/Store_Product_Details',function (req,res) {
    var Name = req.body.Name;
    var Category = req.body.Category;
    var SubCategory = req.body.SubCategory;
    var Description = req.body.Description;
    var date = new Date();
    var ProductData = new ProductSchema({
        name:Name,
        category:Category,
        subcategory:SubCategory,
        description:Description,
        created_at:date
    })
    ProductData.save(function (err,Status) {
        if(!err){
            res.send("Product Stored Successfully");
        }else {
            res.send("Oops! Something went Wrong");
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Updated Answer requested by questioner

Comment: need one more help

Comment: @itsme how can i help u

Answer (score 0):

//Schema definition Example

```
var ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    category:String,
    subcategory:[{
        type:String,
        model:[{
            type:String,
            colour:[{
                name:String,
                image:String
            }],
            size:[{
                val:Number,
                price:Number
            }]
        }]
    }],
    description:String,
    created_at:{ type: Date },
    updated_at:{ type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updated:{type: Date, default: Date.now}
}, { versionKey: false },{strict: false});

export default mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

Comment: can you please give example document

Comment: i want to how i can insert object for this

Comment: //define your Schema Path in your Module where you want to use your Schema

Comment: if i make above schema how product will store in collection

Comment: @itsme i have update my answer  with storing in database

Comment: we need to add key , value pair right ?? and each fabric we need to add images also each color we need to add images

Comment: For Storing to Images u define your Schema as JSON Array as below  color:[[{
        colorcode:String,
        colorname:String,
        ImageURL:String
        
    }]]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147696/discussion-between-its-me-and-ratan-uday-kumar).

Comment: can you please help me out @Ratan Uday Kumar

Comment: i need one more help @Ratan Uday Kumar

Comment: how can i post above product(example product given in question) from controller..

Comment: Will help u from router file

Comment: I have given new answer based on your request and give bounty points to that answer for my hard work

Comment: You set all values of Subcategory and Make a JSON Array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147926/discussion-between-its-me-and-ratan-uday-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

@Ratan Uday Kumar's answer is right, but another but similar way is:

```
var ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    category      :{type:String},
    name          :{type:String},
    description   :{type:String},
    type          :[{type:String}],
    fabric        :[{type:String}],
    size          :[{type:Number}],
    color         :[{type:String}],
    created_at    :{ type: Date },
    updated_at    :{ type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updated:        {type: Date, default: Date.now}
}, { versionKey: false }, {strict: false});

export default mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

{strict: false} is for future! How? Now your schema has 10 fields, if in future you want to add an object with 12 (anything more than 10), you can do it, because there is no strictness in inserting objects with these 10 fields. Even if less fields.

Comment: if i make above schema how product will store ?

Comment: exactly the way you save them! with these fields or maybe without then, completely op to you! Because it's not strict!

Comment: *them (a mistake in commnet above)